# Bundle items are missing from sales_flat_order_item table. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I wonder if somebody faced the same issue or knows what can cause this. For some reason, all bundle items are missing from `sales_flat_order_item` table, so I can't get the parent item. From old db backup, I can find those items were there.

current DB
[image: current DB]

backup
[image: backup]